# Horizontal image list in IOS on top of card

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hi I am trying to achieve this:

[image]

Every search gives me a horizontal list that is contained inside the card and every image disappears into the cards border. Any tips on how to achieve this effect?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, I'm not sure if your question is a programming question, but I'm answering your question anyway.

So you could have `UICollectionView` and each item (row) has another `UICollectionView`.

Since I prefer `UITableView` most of the time, I would use `UITableView` and each row (each `UITableViewCell`) has a `UICollectionView` for displaying the horizontal scrolling albums.

The white container in each cells/rows is merely a `UIView` with constant height and dynamic width (leading and trailing are clipped to the superView with inset, say 10.0). Then the `UICollectionView` is clipped to the superView (`UITableViewCell`) with no offset or zero offset/inset.

If for adding shadows to your view with rounded corners, there are multiple ways to achieve that, but I'm giving you a quick link for your reference: https://medium.com/swifty-tim/views-with-rounded-corners-and-shadows-c3adc0085182

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out!

Comment: Care to explain the downvote, to whoever downvoted this answer? Lol. @Roffe don't forget to choose an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Put three collection views that that stretch between the card borders.  Let the collection views have a transparent background.

Then place the three smaller white views behind the collection views.  Give these views a drop shadow.